# How to list values of one php file in another php file

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am not sure if this is possible !

I have two files say **main.php** and **submenu.php**
In **main.php** i have the following mainMenu
[image]

and in another file called **submenu.php** i have a list say

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

If i click on **Pricelist** in main menu i want to display the content of the submenu as a list under PriceList as

[image]

The simple solution may be including the list view in menu.php itself, But that's not the situation

Thank you.

Comment: [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: why is `include()` not the solution?

Comment: So you want me to try including submenu in my main.php?

Comment: Would you consider jQuery approach?

Comment: @JosephSilber:is it possible without using js or ajax ?

Comment: can be done with pure css(http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/), but most people wouldn't theses days

Comment: Ohh Thankyou @Dagon, Vikram, But i would like to give least priority to jquery. If jQuery is the only solution then i will definitely go for it.

Comment: Wanted to emphasize, as @Dagon mentioned, CSS is a clean and great option too!

Answer (score 1):

You should use arrays and recursion. Like so:

(code is rough, sorry)

```
$menu = array(
    'About Us',
    'Categories',
    'Price List' => array(
         '1','2','3','4'
    )
);


function loop_menu($menu){
    foreach($menu as $m):
        if(is_array($m))
            return '<ul>' . loop_menu($m) . '</ul>';
        else
            return '<li>' . $m . '</li>';
    endforeach;
}

echo loop_menu($menu);
```

Then use CSS to make it look however your want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a page just use 
     include('page.php');

But using JS & CSS is the best way 
Here is a very helpful plugin 
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/
And don't forget to get jQuery